# Datatemplates loaded at runtime fail to override properties

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I'm loading a ResourceDictionary at runtime from an external assembly:

```
ResourceDictionary myResourceDictionary =(ResourceDictionary)reader.LoadAsync(stream);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
```

The ResourceDictionary contains

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MainViewModel}">
        <view:MainView Background="Blue"></view:MainView>
</DataTemplate>
```

MainView is a simple UserControl

```
<UserControl Background="Red"
  ....
>
```

Im setting the DataContext of my ContentControl to an instance of MainViewModel and as expected the MainView usercontrol is shown, but the background is red- (instead of blue, as defined in the DataTemplate). When I remove the Background attribute in the usercontrol, the color defined in the DataTemplate gets applied.

Placed into the applications resources the same DataTemplate works fine.

Any ideas whats wrong here?

Comment: "instead of red, as defined in the DataTemplate"? Blue is defined in the markup you have posted.

Comment: You are right, I got that wrong. I've put it right now. The issue in short is: externally loaded DataTemplates dont override defined properties, while internal defined DataTemplates do.

Comment: So... everything works correctly. Your external style is applied, and, next, your local attributes are being applied, so the background is red. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence

Comment: You should not at all set the "default" UserControl Background directly to Red. Set it in a Style instead.